Using quarkus.swagger-ui.plugins
So this is quarkus specific. I would like to use an external swagger plugin (@kael-shipman/swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags to be specific) but i can't figure out how to configure quarkus to load it. The documentaton has a property listed quarkus.swagger-ui.plugins but no other mention.
I've tried

quarkus.swagger-ui.plugins=@kael-shipman/swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags
quarkus.swagger-ui.plugins=kael-shipman/swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags
quarkus.swagger-ui.plugins=HierarchicalTagsPlugin

The last one makes the most sense to me but i don't know how the library is supposed to get loaded.
